# Parallelize decoding function with OpenMP

Tags: loops, openmp, critical-section

I am trying to parallelize the following decoding function (from binary code to int):

```c
int decodePrimeFactorization(int code){
  int prod = 1;
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int j=0; j<PF_NUMBER ; j++){
      #pragma omp critical
      {
          if ((code & 1) == 1){
              prod = prod * prime_factors[j];
          }
          code = code / 2;
      }
   } 
   return(prod);
}
```

Although the loop section is critical, the result is still wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of downvoting the question, please explain how can I improve it.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but I think putting a critical pragma that cover all lines of parallel loop is nonsense. so what should be paralleled?

Comment: I agree. I started by using two atomic directives on the two instructions but that didn't work. So I tried this one (although it brings no advantage) just to check if it would give a correct result, it still didn't work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop as written can not be made parallel as the value of your `code` variable is dependent on which iteration of the loop you are in.  When making a loop parallel each iteration of the loop must be independent.  For a value like `code` you need to rewrite to leave the loop external value constant and use a loop internal value that is dependent on the loop iterator `j`. You also should make the critical section as small as possible; here the only critical action is updating `prod`.

```
int decodePrimeFactorization(int code){
int prod = 1;
#pragma omp parallel for
  for (int j=0; j<PF_NUMBER ; j++){
    int code_tmp = (code >> j); // replaces code = code / 2
    if ((code_tmp & 1) == 1){
      #pragma omp critical
      {
        prod = prod * prime_factors[j];
      }
    }
  } 
  return(prod);
}
```

I use a loop internal value `code_tmp` to make it clearer what is required but you could also just replace the if statement with `if (((code >> j) & 1) == 1)...`.

This is typical of many parallel loops where you have to do potentially more computation in each loop to replace values that are carried between each loop iteration in a serial version.

Comment: That makes too much sense, I shouldn't have provoked dependent iterations. Thank you!